# CSV programming read write

Tags: python, list, csv

I'm trying to write a program that reads a list of `CSV` student scores and does the following:

The program calculates an exam average for each student and rounds it up to an integer using math ceil, then it writes the name and the exam average to another `csv` file called `examScores.csv` Names and scores of students within 5 points of the maximum score, e.g if the maximum score is 98, then all the students scoring >= 93 should be printed.
The number of students that scored in the range 0 – 59, 60 – 69, 70 – 79, 80 – 89, 90 – 100 (to keep track of the ranges, you should set up a list of counters of size 5; when you process a number within the first range, you update location 0, within second range, location 1, etc).

I'm having a fairly hard time with this. Here is the code I've concocted so far:

```
inpt1=open("grades.csv","r")
outpt1=open("examscores.csv","w")
studentname=[]
studentlastname=[]
gradeav=[]
highav=0
inpt1.readline()

for line in inpt1:
   data=line.split(",")
   averages=math.ceil(data[2])+float(data[3])/2
   studentname.append(data[0])
   studentlastname.append(data[1])
   gradeav.append(averages)
inpt1.close()
outpt1.close()
```

I can't get the math ceil function to work and my appending isn't working as well. Granted I don't want anyone to solve this for me, just need a hint or push in the right direction.

Comment: I suggest looking at threads that cover proper opening and reading of csv files, saving this data to a list, and doing averages on lists. There are several mistakes in your code, all of which are explained in the great examples of all 3 on here. It may be easier ultimately to use a list of dictionaries to store your data, but if that gets too complex you can technically stick with a bunch of separate lists.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you are asking for a hint, I will give it a shot.

Note that you are separately recording the names and grades. What is more useful is to record these values in a coherent data structure. I prefer a list of list. Start off with

```
records = []
```

Follow that with file read, line split and value extraction. Then insert it into the records.

```
records.append([average, last_name, first_name])
```

At the end of the loop, sort the records by the first column in descending order. Hint: google "python list of list sorted lambda". From the sorted list, pick out the max and those 5 points below it. I will leave that as an exercise for you.

You can also use the sorted list to split into different ranges. Hint: google "python bisect package".

As for your issues with math.ceil, try

```
average = math.ceil(0.5* (float(data[2]) + float(data[3])))
```

Let me know if more hints are needed. :-)